# How to trigger a NPAPI (hardware related) plugin in the absence of an html/mime/content tag?

Tags: npapi, firebreath

If this is a borderline question I would appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction or a more appropriate web site venue for this kind of query.

I am very much a web newb and trying to figure out the following: how to trigger a NPAPI plugin in the absence of an appropriate tag?

My understanding is that plugins are triggered by MIME content tags in the html stream from the server for which the plugin has registered itself in the browser.  This seems to require that the server be a participant in that it places the tag in the stream.

I have a situation where I need to access some hardware via a plugin from an generic (non-participating in the above sense) web site.  For instance, any html stream with a login field should trigger an event (if that is the appropriate term) that calls the plugin.  Is this possible in this - or any other - way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.  Plugins are only instantiated by mimetype or object/embed tag.  You could potentially add an extension that would inject said plugin into the page, though.

see http://npapi.com/extensions

Comment: Thank you.  I was afraid of that.  Unfortunately your link is broken, do you know the updated URL?  I know from the information I have gathered on this topic thus far that you are an expert on this topic.  Do you think an extension is a realistic option?

Comment: copy/paste error, sorry =] Fixed it now.  (missing the trailing s)

Comment: As you'll need an extension anyway, there's no need to inject the plugin into pages. You could just have the plugin running in the background (using [page-worker](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/page-worker.html) i think) or use ctypes instead.

Comment: @Georg Fritzsche, I assume you mean the extension, not a plugin, would need to be running in the background?  My puzzlement is over what mechanism to use in the face of NPAPI's demise.  I must have something (extension or plugin) that allows me to call a C library that controls my hardware from the browser.  My impression was that NPAPI was the only mechanism to do this.  If an extension can do this on its own then that is great but I am unsure if that is the case.  Do you have insight or experience on this point?

Comment: The demise of NPAPI? Chrome is the only browser that has so far indicated that they will not be supporting NPAPI, and this question seems unrelated to that.  Your question was how to instantiate a plugin without a tag; @GeorgFritzsche was clarifying my suggestion that you could use an extension to inject the plugin into the page.  He was pointing out that if you were using an extension anyway, you could have the extension contain a persistent background instance of the plugin.

Comment: taxilian - I don't have a dog in this fight, I just have a problem to solve.   My initial problem was instantiating a tagless plugin.  But if said plugins have a limited future that's an issue for me and I am trying to figure out a more durable solution.   I need to communicate from the all the major browsers to a piece of hardware.  Whatever its other problems, NPAPI seems to have fulfilled this role.  But my hardware has to go through retail channels and the time lag, expense and recall possibilities that entails.

Comment: Every vendor going off in different directions is sub-optimal but (assuming PPAPI fulfills my needs) at least Google has made a decision.  The uncertainty of the fence sitters (e.g. Mozilla) are more problematic.  I am trying to find a solution that doesn't render an expensive hardware roll-out into paper weights by the time the product reaches the consumer.

Comment: Note that PPAPI isn't usable to 3rd parties except as part of NACL. For hardware access like you're describing you'd need to use their Native Messaging